# Passing firebase data to components in React

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ItemField from './ItemField';
class App extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <ItemField /> 
            <ItemField /> 
            <ItemField /> 
            <ItemField /> 
            <ItemField /> 
            <ItemField /> 
            <ItemField /> 
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default App;


import React from 'react';  
import ModalOffer from './ModalOffer';
class ItemField extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div id="borrow-div">
          <table class="borrower-table">
            <tr id="top-sec">
              <td id="prof-pic" width="100"><img class="img" src="a_firebase_img" /></td>
              <td id="product">item name</td>
              <td>
                <div id="offer">
                  <ModalOffer />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="bottom-sec">
              <td class="search-info">12:20AM</td>
              <td class="search-info">3 days ago</td>
              <td class="search-info">City, Province</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default ItemField;
```

---

Hello, I am wondering what would be the best way to pass information to the components. Currently I have default values set in place.The goal is to have each item field populated with the most recent search item with their components.

Would the best method be the set an initial state and change the state with information retrieved from firebase?

```
├── _Item1
|   ├── User
|   ├── Time
|   ├── City
|   ├── Province
├── _Item2
|   ├── User
|   ├── Time
|   ├── City
|   ├── Province
```

This is the FireBase structure.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You things in props e.g. `<ItemField myProp={value} />`

from component, do `{myProp} = this.props`